# How can I find duplicate values in a column delimiting the results by ranges in a different column?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

```
     A          B            C
1  RANGES     VALUES   FORMULA NEEDED  
2    1          x           yes
3    1          x           yes
4    2          x           no
5    3                      no
6    3          y           yes
7    3          y           yes
8    4          x           no
9    5          z           no
10   5          y           no
```

So, I want to identify duplicates in VALUES, delimiting results by values in RANGES. I'd like the result to be like in the FORMULA NEEDED column.

What I need are the duplicate values from the VALUES column. More specifically, I need to see if what I find in the VALUES column is a duplicate, using (this is important) the range of duplicates from the RANGES column as a delimiter. I hope that made sense.

So if: - x is duplicated within the rows that are numbered 1, this is a yes. 
- y is duplicated within the rows numbered 3, even with blank values or additional values such as x thrown in there, this is still a yes.

This is my failed attempt:

```
=IF(AND(A2=A1,B2=B1),"yes","no")
```

Comment: I suspect you'll need to try a VLOOKUP (I don't know enough about it) , or do it using VBa

Comment: A common way to do this is with a helper column.  Add a column with, for row 2: =A2&B2  and copy that down the range.  Then look for duplicates in that column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use VBA.

So what You need to do is read the values of column A + B into an array.
Lets say that we have an [array](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html) named `C`, so C(1) will be A2 + B2 = "1x"; C(2) will be A3 + B3 = "1x"; C(3): A4 + B4 = "2x"; etc.
You do a for loop for this to read in all values that You have to C(i).

After You have this, You just google `excel vba how to find duplicate values in an array`
I am sure there will be lots of solutions for this.

After You got this, You will probably get an array that stores values into another or the same array for example in Booleans (true/false)

So You just run another for loop on it, that will look something like:
`for i = 1 to NumberOfRows
if C(i) = true then Cells(i, "C").Value = "true"
next i`

Of course there are more possible solutions, but this is how I would do it.
If You have questions, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Did You manage to solve the problem? If my post helped, remember to accept it, so the post can be closed. If You solved it in another way, please answer your question describing the solution in a few words.